# How to inject and load all sass files on ssr in next.js?

Tags: next.js, sass, server-side-rendering, fouc

This is my first Question on this Platform and I really need your HELP!
The Problem is FOUC in NextJs@14.0.3
i need to minify and extract all my sass files to render on Server to avoid FOUC error

I have been searching for about 5 days and now I am really disappointed

I tried critters and {cssOptimize:true} but did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.